# How to read touch screen input on android

Tags: c#, android, monogame, porting

I'm trying to port a one-click game to Android, using monogame but as my first time doing this I'm struggling to figure out how I can read if the user has pressed the screen or not. I'm also unsure what library to use, most logical seams Android.Gestures but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a touch collection: `TouchCollection touchState;//get touches`

In `Update()` method of `Game1()` or the class you want to implement:

```
            touchState = TouchPanel.GetState();

            foreach (var touch in touchState)
            {                    
                if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                {
                    //do what you want here when users tap the screen
                }                
            }
```

It uses `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;`